# check Checkbox using string values

Tags: android, checkbox

I am using custom checkbox.I have to set two checkbox values in checkbox.I am getting two values in spot_types.

**Logcat:**

> E/spot_types : 1,5

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
    CheckBox checkBox;


  spot_types = bundle.getString("spot_types");

  Log.e("spot_types",""+spot_types);
```

So far I have tried `checkBox.setChecked()`.But it is not working.I dont know how to check the checkbox values using spot_types string values.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

**Edit:** I am getting the spot_types values from json response and I have to check those two values in custom checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **ExampleAdapter**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.creatrixone.R;
import com.creatrixone.ThemeColor;
import com.creatrixone.helpers.JSONHandler;
import com.creatrixone.helpers.TextDrawable;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private JSONArray data;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean[] checkBoxState;
    private String[] selectedpositions;
    private TextDrawable check, uncheck;


    public ExampleAdapter(Activity activity, JSONArray data, String[] selectedpositions) {
        this.mContext = activity;
        this.data = data;                          //no.of rows in your listview
        this.selectedpositions=selectedpositions;  // you need to pass your spot_types in  array
        checkBoxState = new boolean[data.length()];

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length();
    }

    public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        return JSONHandler.getJSONObjectFromJSONArray(data, position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.co_filter_row, null);

            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_content);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.textview.setText("Title");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            String Id = JSONHandler.getStringFromJSONObject(getItem(i), "Id");
            for (int j = 0; j < selectedpositions.length; j++) {
                try {
                    if (Id.equals(jsonArray.get(j))) { //implement your logic here
                        checkBoxState[i] = true;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
       holder.checkbox.setSelected(checkBoxState[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                checkBoxState[position] = isChecked;


            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }


}
```